# Plot the U-Net network architecture based on the model code

Tags: python, matplotlib, deep-learning, image-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I am currently working on medical image segmentation project and I am using U-Net architecture to train my dataset and perform segmentation. I wanted to view how my coded architecture looks like and i tried many ways to achive the same.I was not able to plot the architecture of my code on U-Net.

This is the code. It is the code for the U-net architecture

```
from torchvision.transforms import CenterCrop
from torch.nn import functional as F
import torch

class Block(Module):
    def __init__(self, inChannels, outChannels):
        super().__init__()
        # store the convolution and RELU layers
        self.conv1 = Conv2d(inChannels, outChannels, 3)
        self.relu = ReLU()
        self.conv2 = Conv2d(outChannels, outChannels, 3)
    def forward(self, x):
        # apply CONV => RELU => CONV block to the inputs and return it
        return self.conv2(self.relu(self.conv1(x)))

class Encoder(Module):
    def __init__(self, channels=(3, 16, 32, 64)):
        super().__init__()
        # store the encoder blocks and maxpooling layer
        self.encBlocks = ModuleList(
            [Block(channels[i], channels[i + 1])
                for i in range(len(channels) - 1)])
        self.pool = MaxPool2d(2)

    def forward(self, x):
        # initialize an empty list to store the intermediate outputs
        blockOutputs = []

        # loop through the encoder blocks
        for block in self.encBlocks:
            # pass the inputs through the current encoder block, store
            # the outputs, and then apply maxpooling on the output
            x = block(x)
            blockOutputs.append(x)
            x = self.pool(x)
        # return the list containing the intermediate outputs
        return blockOutputs


class Decoder(Module):
    def __init__(self, channels=(64, 32, 16)):
        super().__init__()
        # initialize the number of channels, upsampler blocks, and
        # decoder blocks
        self.channels = channels
        self.upconvs = ModuleList(
            [ConvTranspose2d(channels[i], channels[i + 1], 2, 2)
                for i in range(len(channels) - 1)])
        self.dec_blocks = ModuleList(
            [Block(channels[i], channels[i + 1])
                for i in range(len(channels) - 1)])
        #deco = self.upconvs + self.dec_blocks
        #3return deco
    def forward(self, x, encFeatures):
        # loop through the number of channels
        for i in range(len(self.channels) - 1):
            # pass the inputs through the upsampler blocks
            x = self.upconvs[i](x)
            # crop the current features from the encoder blocks,
            # concatenate them with the current upsampled features,
            # and pass the concatenated output through the current
            # decoder block
            encFeat = self.crop(encFeatures[i], x)
            x = torch.cat([x, encFeat], dim=1)
            x = self.dec_blocks[i](x)
        # return the final decoder output
        return x
    def crop(self, encFeatures, x):
        # grab the dimensions of the inputs, and crop the encoder
        # features to match the dimensions
        (_, _, H, W) = x.shape
        encFeatures = CenterCrop([H, W])(encFeatures)
        # return the cropped features
        return encFeatures

class UNet(Module):
    def __init__(self, encChannels=(3, 16, 32, 64),
         decChannels=(64, 32, 16),
         nbClasses=1, retainDim=True,
         outSize=(config.INPUT_IMAGE_HEIGHT,  config.INPUT_IMAGE_WIDTH)):
        super().__init__()
        # initialize the encoder and decoder
        self.encoder = Encoder(encChannels)
        self.decoder = Decoder(decChannels)
        # initialize the regression head and store the class variables
        self.head = Conv2d(decChannels[-1], nbClasses, 1)
        self.retainDim = retainDim
        self.outSize = outSize

    def forward(self, x):
        # grab the features from the encoder
        encFeatures = self.encoder(x)
        # pass the encoder features through decoder making sure that
        # their dimensions are suited for concatenation
        decFeatures = self.decoder(encFeatures[::-1][0],
                                   encFeatures[::-1][1:])
        # pass the decoder features through the regression head to
        # obtain the segmentation mask
        map = self.head(decFeatures)
        # check to see if we are retaining the original output
        # dimensions and if so, then resize the output to match them
        if self.retainDim:
            map = F.interpolate(map, self.outSize)
        # return the segmentation map
        return map
```

I used plot_model function  but i am not getting any result.

I used a code similar to this to visualize the U-Net architecture.

```
from keras.utils import plot_model
#  Build your model
model = UNet

# Visualize the model
plot_model(model, to_file='model2.png')
```

Please help me plot a network architecture based on my U-Net code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tensorboard to plot the UNet architecture this is an example of the code I have used

```
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
import torch
from unet_model import UNet
# Create the UNet model
model = UNet(1,6,48)

# Create a dummy input tensor
x = torch.randn(1, 1, 256, 256)

# Create a SummaryWriter object to log the information
writer = SummaryWriter("logs")

# Log the model graph to the writer
writer.add_graph(model, x)

# Close the writer
writer.close()

# Launch TensorBoard to view the logs
!tensorboard --logdir=logs
```